# Can I autopopulate between different users' forms with Rules and Webforms or EntityForms?

Tags: rules, forms

I need to create a form in which some fields auto-populate with the values submitted on other users' forms. Specifically, the manager has to submit a form documenting the progress of projects a, b, and c. However, the manager needs the option to ask another staffer to complete a form for one of the projects. So when the staffer submits the form, their value of textarea field "Project B Status" autopopulates into the field "Project B Status" on the manager's form. The manager can then edit staffer's text if necessary and submit the final report.

I have tried doing this using both WebForms and EntityForms and have tried using Rules to autopopulate. I cannot get it to work right, but before I continue I would like to know if these are the best modules to use or if I am doing something wrong (as I am fairly new to Drupal).

Many of the answers I have seen on this issue involve editing the actual php, which I would prefer not to do at this point (but will if someone can tell me specifically what to do).

Answer (score 0):

If I were to approach the problem, each project would be a node.

- First install the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) ([documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1353926)) and [Field Permission](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) modules.
- Create a new Content Type (`admin/structure/types/add`) and call it *Project*.
- Assign the fields you want filled in (`admin/structure/types/manage/project/fields`).
- Add an additional field called *Project Status* of type "Field Collection" and choose "Embedded" as the widget type. Click save, leave **Hide blank items** checked on the next page, then click save again.
- Go to the Field Collections page (`admin/structure/field-collections`). You'll see your new *Project Status* field listed. Click "Manage fields" and add your subform fields here.
- At this point, your manager should be able to create new *Project* nodes, and the *Project Status* field will hold the additional information. You'll need to set up the field permissions so that the staffer role can only edit the *Project Status* field.

  Back on your node fields page (`admin/structure/types/manage/project/fields`) edit each field. Near the bottom of each field's settings, look for the **Field visibility and permissions** section. Choose the **Custom permissions** radio button and look at the settings available. For your project, you want to allow your staffer role the ability to edit anyone's value for the *Project Status* field, but none of the other fields.
- Remember to also set permissions to allow the manager role to create *Project* nodes, and the staffer role to edit *Project* nodes (`admin/people/permissions#module-node`).

As an added bonus, you can set the field settings for the *Project Status* field to allow an unlimited number of values. This would allow for updated status as the project progresses. YMMV of course.